# how can I create a new column with two columns combination?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want a new column that contains the amount of times user_id and artist_id are the same, for example if user_id = 0, and artist_id = 10, and it happens 5 times, i want to store number 5 in a column in the 5 rows in which this occurs.
This code gives me the value, but I can't store it.

```
treino.groupby(['user_id', 'artist_id']).count()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you need a column that represents the size of each group in each row. Then you need to use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).

```
df["group_size"] = (
    df.assign(group_size=1)
    .groupby(["user_id", "artist_id"])["group_size"]
    .transform("count")
)
```